# How to deal with changing user_pseudo_id?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have a mobile app and I use firebase and BigQuery to download data for analysis. Recently the 'user_pseudo_id' has been changing when 'app_remove' event is triggered. When I emailed firebase, they replied that 'user_pseudo_id' changes when app cache is cleared.

We rely on 'user_pseudo_id' to calculate app removes in new users (daily). Can you suggest a solution to this problem?

We cannot use the 'user_id' as it will not be triggered for 'first_open' event using which we find daily new users.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For Apps, `user_pseudo_id` is the [`app_instance_id`](https://developers.google.com/instance-id). The `app_instance_id` is updated with each app install. This means, when an App is removed/uninstalled from a device, the `app_remove` is the final event for an `app_instance_id`. If an app is reinstalled on a device, that 'app instance' will have a new `app_instance_id` i.e. a new `user_pseudo_id`. This is working as intended, has always been this way, and is not a recent change.

For your use case, you need to fully articulate: "*We rely on 'user_pseudo_id' to calculate app removes in new users (daily).*". e.g. How are you defining new users?

Since you do not want to use `user_id`, the only way for you to define new users is by using `user_pseudo_id`s.

If you want to calculate new users who are uninstalling the app in their first session, you can write a query for that.